# What are the challenges I might face when I switch from electronic drum-kit (Yamaha DD65) to an acoustic drum-set?

Tags: technique, drums, performing

I currently play drums on a Yamaha DD65. Never played on an acoustic before. So I was wondering what kind of issues I might have when I switch. Is there anything I should keep in mind when I play on acoustic drum-set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are several things that are different:

- You'll find out that a real drum and a real cymbal produce much more variants in sound than the electronic version, depending on many parameters of your stroke (where you hit, how hard you hit, what kind of stick you have, how tight you hold the stick). It is a challenge, but also a possibility.
- You cannot balance your instruments with volume faders any more, you need to adjust your playing to get a balanced sound within your set.
- Another difference will be the physical setup of your kit. Real drums have different sizes and are deeper than electronic ones, so the distance from one drum to the other one will be bigger for an acoustic set.
- If you're on the road a lot, you'll also notice the difference in weight and space for an acoustic kit.
- And finally (but unlikely): if you're a heavy hitter you should consider that real cymbals (especially thin models) can be damaged and get cracks if you hit them to hard in a too steep angle.
- Of course, there are the obvious differences: acoustic sets don't need power and can disturb your neighbors.
- Depending of your tuning, there is usualy less bounce on acoustic heads than on meshed heads.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is that mesh-head electronic drums are easier to play and when you get back to your acoustic set on stage and have to beat the hell out of them to be heard you'll find you've been very spoiled by the electronic drums. Don't let them fool you.....

Answer (score 1):

Just checked what that kit looks like: [image].

I'm not a drumnmer, but I've played on acoustic, rubber pad and mesh type electric drums. You will face some more issues when switching to acoustics due to the set up of these drums. You have much more distance between drums and especially the cymbals. You'll have to play in a quite different posture. That thing does not invite a hard beating, so I think you should focus on hitting the drums hard when you switch. There's a big difference in how rubber pads and and the acoustic drum feel when you hit them, you've also had nothing that tries to imitate a cymbal. In short, it will be a new instrument.

Also, acoustic drums are loud as hell, so you might want to consider practising with ear plugs...

Comment: Beside the pad positions, cymbals and hit-hat are mounted on a stopper with a felt washer and wing nut : they are moving. The drum bass pedal is a way different also, a chain link and a spring gives you a natural comeback when you hit the drum. On a real battery (accoustic or electronic like a Roland V-Drum), the kit is more alive and will respond to the way you are playing and you'll have to adapt your moves to the comebacks of the kit/pads/drums. This kit on the photo is more a practice drum or a multipad than a drum set.